# ARM GNU GCC(C++) path configuration related issue on Eclipse Platform

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, arm, freertos

I'm trying to make Wrapper class for FreeRTOS on ARM GNU compiler with C++. I did it on **Keil MDK-ARM v5.14** without any problem but I cant accomplish on eclipse platform. I think it is about my wrong **Source Location** configuration on eclipse.

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, ARM GNU GCC 4.9.2 and GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-ins

Here is my Wrapper class interface:

```
#ifndef TASKOOP_H_
#define TASKOOP_H_

#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"

class TaskOOP {
private:
    TaskHandle_t _handle;
public:
    TaskOOP();
    virtual ~TaskOOP();//xTaskCreate( vTaskCode, "NAME", STACK_SIZE, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &xHandle );
    void create(const char * const pcName, const uint16_t usStackDepth, UBaseType_t uxPriority);    //xTaskCreate( pvTaskCode, pcName, usStackDepth, pvParameters, uxPriority, pxCreatedTask )
    void deleteT(); //vTaskDelete( TaskHandle_t xTaskToDelete )
    void suspend(); //vTaskSuspend( TaskHandle_t xTaskToSuspend )
    void resume();  //vTaskResume( TaskHandle_t xTaskToResume )
    UBaseType_t getTaskPriority();                      //uxTaskPriorityGet( TaskHandle_t xTask )
    void setTaskPriority(UBaseType_t uxNewPriority);    //vTaskPrioritySet( TaskHandle_t xTask, UBaseType_t uxNewPriority )

    static void delay(const TickType_t xTicksToDelay);  //vTaskDelay( const TickType_t xTicksToDelay )
    static void vTaskStartScheduler( void );
    static void vTaskEndScheduler( void );
    static void vTaskSuspendAll( void );
    static BaseType_t xTaskResumeAll( void );

private:
    static void bridge(void* pThis);
protected:
    virtual void run(void) = 0;

};

#endif /* TASKOOP_H_ */
```

Here is my implementation:

```
#include "TaskOOP.h"

TaskOOP::TaskOOP():_handle(0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

TaskOOP::~TaskOOP() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void TaskOOP::create(const char * const pcName, const uint16_t usStackDepth, UBaseType_t uxPriority){

    xTaskCreate(bridge,pcName,usStackDepth,this,uxPriority,&_handle);
}

void TaskOOP::deleteT(){

    vTaskDelete(_handle);
}

void TaskOOP::suspend(){

    vTaskSuspend(_handle);
}

void TaskOOP::resume(){

    vTaskResume(_handle);
}

UBaseType_t  TaskOOP::getTaskPriority(){

    return uxTaskPriorityGet(_handle);
}

void TaskOOP::setTaskPriority(UBaseType_t uxNewPriority){

    vTaskPrioritySet(  _handle,  uxNewPriority );
}

void TaskOOP::delay(const TickType_t xTicksToDelay){

    vTaskDelay(xTicksToDelay);
}

void TaskOOP::vTaskStartScheduler(void){

    vTaskStartScheduler();
}

void TaskOOP::vTaskEndScheduler(void){

    vTaskEndScheduler();
}

void TaskOOP::vTaskSuspendAll(void){

    vTaskSuspendAll();
}

BaseType_t TaskOOP::xTaskResumeAll( void ){

    return xTaskResumeAll();
}

void TaskOOP::bridge(void* pThis){
    TaskOOP* task = (TaskOOP *)pThis;
    task->run();
}
```

Here are some print-screens from my eclipse settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I cant upload them as image because I dont have enough reputation.

So the question is how should I configure my **Path** and **Source Location**?

Comment: There's a bunch of tangential information here but no actual problem statement. _What_ doesn't work, and _how_? If you get error messages, what are they? I think it's vanishingly unlikely that anyone can infer what the real problem is from what's here, much less the solution. Are you using an external makefile, or a CDT autogenerated one? Unless it's the latter, the project path settings are largely irrelevant. Those unmentioned errors partly visible in the images look to be down to incorrect compiler options more than anything else.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you for allow time to me. And Sorry for my late answer.


Finally I solved my issue(But there is one  small problem).
Every one can take a look my simple demo at : https://bitbucket.org/Namcho/freertos_gcc_stm32f3/overview